# Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul_46' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [100,100], [?,15,100]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got that error when trying to implement this lines of code

Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul_46' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [100,100], [?,15,100].

```
Q = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 15))
word_level = Embedding ( vocab_size , 100 , input_length=15)(Q) 
#shape(?,15,100)
Wb = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 100]))
C = tf.matmul( word_level ,Wb)
```

I think the problem because different rank of matrices of 3 & 2 dimension
but I do not know how to modify this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify a tensor to fit a certain shape you can use `tf.reshape`, but be careful to reshape it in a way that makes sense.

See the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape)

```
reshape = tf.reshape(word_level, [-1, 100])
Wb = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 100]))
C = tf.matmul(reshape ,Wb)
```

Comment: I want to construct Wb for each batch size so the final answer be with shape (? , 15 ,100)